# Hide dropped element

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a drag and drop where i want to hide the dropped image. The issue that i have is that the images all have the same `class` and hiding by the `class` drops hides all the images including those that have not yet been dropped. I have tried the `$(this).Hide();` but however this hides the droppabble rather than the dragged image.

Code for the images:

```
 using (The_Factory.Models.The_FactoryDBContext db2 = new The_Factory.Models.The_FactoryDBContext())
                {

                    string imageSource = "";

                    av = db2.Letter_Activity.ToList().FirstOrDefault(a => a.name == qs);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {

                        if (av != null)
                        {
                            string imageBase = Convert.ToBase64String(av.image);
                            imageSource = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase);


                            <img src="@imageSource" class="draggable correct" id="@av.name"/>

                        }
                    }
                }
```

This is the code for my droppable

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
        accept: '.correct',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(".correct").hide();
    });

    $("#playAgain").click(function () {
        location.reload(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element dragged is accessible via the `ui` argument as `ui.draggable`.

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
        accept: '.correct',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.hide();  // hide the element dragged...
    });

    $("#playAgain").click(function () {
        location.reload(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the element when it is droped.

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
        accept: '.correct',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass("dropped");
            $(".dropped").hide();
    });

    $("#playAgain").click(function () {
        location.reload(true);
    });
});
```

It would probably be better to hide the .dropped class in css

```
.dropped{display:none;}
```

Comment: The `this` reference in this context refers to the droppable. So instead of hiding the image it hides the droppable.